# R Groupby by column to return unique values in multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

this is mostly likely a duplicate - let me know and I'll delete.

I have some dataframe:

```
   from   to  value sourceID targetID clustid
1  1400 1413 0.6846  3055586  3060697       1
2   323  661 0.5550  1596205   724084       1
3   323 1411 0.6817   724084  3060607       1
4  1413 1411 0.6729  3060697  3060607       1
5  1498 1411 0.6381  3111960  3060607       1
6  1478 1415 0.7423  3062164  3099199       2
7  1478 1414 0.7423  3099199  3062163       2
8  1415 1462 0.7078  3090708  3062164       2
9  1415 1463 0.7078  3062164  3090709       2
10 1462 1404 0.7078  3090708  3058341       2
```

I want to carry out an equivalent to the Python Pandas `groupby()` function to group my data according to `clustid`.

In addition, I then want to return a new dataframe containing the unique values of `sourceID` and `targetID` and sort those values. This is such that my output will be:

```
 UniqueID
1 724084
  1596205
  3055586
  3060607
  3060697
  3111960
2 3058341
  3062163
  3062164
  3090708
  3090709
  3099199
```

I know I can use `unique()` to return a list of the Unique Ids for all rows of the `sourceID` and `targetID` column as follows:

```
unique_ids <- sort(unique(c((df$sourceID), (df$targetID))))
> unique_ids
 [1]  370871  370873  374920  431814  612944  724084 1145838 1145839 1312582 1365467 1365468 1450552 1450553 1469099 1477137 1519842 1528881 1596205 1919812 1935866
[21] 2933725 2933726 3018082 3055586 3058341 3060607 3060697 3062163 3062164 3064884 3064885 3083388 3090708 3090709 3099199 3111960 3458397
```

But how can this be done only for a specific `clustid` and the result stored as a dataframe above?

Many thanks for your help.

@Sotos recommendation got me:

```
lapply(split(df, df$clustid), function(i) sort(unique(c(i$sourceID, i$targetID))))
$`1`
[1]  724084 1596205 3055586 3060607 3060697 3111960

$`2`
[1] 3058341 3062163 3062164 3090708 3090709 3099199

$`3`
[1]  612944 1919812 1935866 3018082 3064884 3064885

$`4`
[1] 1312582 1365467 1365468 2933725 2933726 3083388 3458397

$`5`
[1] 1450552 1450553 1469099 1477137 1519842 1528881

$`6`
[1]  370871  370873  374920  431814 1145838 1145839
```

Unfortunately this is not quite what I'm after.

Comment: Try `lapply(split(df, df$clustid), function(i) sort(unique(c(i$sourceID, i$targetID))))`

Comment: Added output into answer. Not quite right unfortunately :/

Comment: @ChuckM, that should work. Are you using a different data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bind_rows` from `dplyr` for quick and easy transformation to data frame along with the IDs, i.e.

```
dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(split(df, df$clustid), 
                 function(i)data.frame(IDs = sort(unique(c(i$sourceID, i$targetID))))), 
                                                                          .id = 'cluster')
#   cluster     IDs
#1        1  724084
#2        1 1596205
#3        1 3055586
#4        1 3060607
#5        1 3060697
#6        1 3111960
#7        2 3058341
#8        2 3062163
#9        2 3062164
#10       2 3090708
#11       2 3090709
#12       2 3099199
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to suppress having a cluster id for each row?

Comment: Why? Is it worth to go through the trouble?

Comment: I suppose I should have mentioned in the question -> These dataframes are to be outputted as html tables using `formattable` or `knitr`. The suppresion fits with the desired output format for these tables, I was hoping there might be a way to do it before outputting.

Comment: Hey Sotos, thanks for the answer, tested the use case and this will do nicely :) Many thanks and have nice day!

Comment: can we get the final result in vector or list form where names of the list are ID and values is a vector of values?

Answer (score 2):

Heres's a solution using the `data.table` package. Assuming your table is stored in a data frame called `df`.

```
df <- data.table(df)
df <- df[, list(id = unique(c(targetID, sourceID))), by = clustid]
setkeyv(df, c("clustid", "id"))
```

The contents of `df` is then

```
##     clustid      id
##  1:       1  724084
##  2:       1 1596205
##  3:       1 3055586
##  4:       1 3060607
##  5:       1 3060697
##  6:       1 3111960
##  7:       2 3058341
##  8:       2 3062163
##  9:       2 3062164
## 10:       2 3090708
## 11:       2 3090709
## 12:       2 3099199
```

Comment: Cheers Aaron for the answer, really appreciate the feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe using `dplyr` and `tidyr` you can do a `gather` operation to bring the two id columns into one. An operation like

```
df %>%
  group_by(clustid) %>%
  gather(idtype, uniqueID, sourceID, targetID) %>%
  arrange(uniqueID) %>%
  unique() %>%
  select(clustid, uniqueID) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Should do the trick.